# Server error 502 when deploying .NET Core RC2 in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, .net-core-rc2

I developed an MVC web site using .NET Core RC2 in VS Code on my Mac and I tried to deploy it in Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS. I used https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html as reference. My project.json has `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration`, and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel`. My startup.cs has `app.UseStaticFiles`, `app.UseSession` and `app.UseMVC`.

I did

- Review my IIS installation
- Install .NET Core Windows Server Hosting Bundle and reset IIS
- Copy all files to the server
- Create web site and set application pool to `No Managed Code` as .NET CLR version
- Add the default web.config for a .NET Core web site
- Grant Application pool identity access to the files
- Try to set the root at both project root and wwwroot

And I get the following error

> **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.** There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: When you say you copied all files to the server, how exactly did you do that? Did you run dotnet publish and dotnet publish-iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [cesarbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407094/cesarbs) hint I have made a `dotnet publish`, copied the generated folder to the website root and I recycled the application pool. It worked beautifully.